# What is the difference between proving something for an arbitrary object and proving something using a universal quantifier?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

I think I am a little out of my depth in asking this question, but I'll give it a go.

I am having trouble distinguishing between proving something for an arbitrary object of some type (something that I believe can be 'encoded' in **sentential logic**), which then generalizes to all objects of the same type, and proving something using a universal quantifier (which I believe can only be encoded in **predicate logic**).

I came across this issue, in particular, when I tried proving the **Deduction Theorem**. Firstly, some necessary background:

In the book "*Model Theory*", the "...notion of a formal deduction in [the] logic $\mathscr S$" is introduced in the following paragraph:

> The Rule of Detachment states: From $\psi$ and $\psi \rightarrow \varphi$ infer $\varphi$. Now consider a finite or infinite set of $\Sigma$ of $\mathscr S$. A sentence $\varphi$ is *deducible from $\Sigma$*, in symbols $\Sigma \vdash \varphi$, iff there is a finite sequence $\psi_0,\psi_1,...,\psi_n$ of sentences such that $\varphi = \psi_n$ and each sentence $\psi_m$ is either a tautology, belongs to $\Sigma$, or is inferred from two earlier sentences of the sequence by detachment.

In my book, the **Deduction Theorem** for sentential logic is posed as follows:

If $\Sigma \cup \{\psi\} \vdash \varphi$, then $\Sigma \vdash \psi \rightarrow \varphi$

**Firstly**, by completing this proof, aren't I really saying the following?

$\forall \Sigma, \forall \varphi, \forall \psi$   $ \ \ $ If $\Sigma \cup \{\psi\} \vdash \varphi$, then $\Sigma \vdash \psi \rightarrow \varphi]$

This, in and of itself, is already confusing because it seems like I am utilizing a higher order logic system's terminology in order to describe a result from a lower order logic system.

---

**Secondly**, consider the proof for the Deduction Theorem ( provided here https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Deduction_Theorem) that is depicted below. Note that the language is slightly different...the change in notation is:

If $U, A \vdash B$, then $U \vdash A \rightarrow B$

[image: Proof]

I have marked in $\color{red}{\text {red}}$ the line that is causing me some grief.

After completing the base case for $n=1$, the proof states (implicitly) that our hypothesis case is:

> Assume for a proof of size $n$ (i.e. $\theta_1 \theta_2...\theta_n$ where $\theta_n = B$) $\ \ \ $ If $U, A \vdash B$, then $U \vdash A \rightarrow B$.

In the $n+1$ step, the proof invokes the hypothesis in order to stipulate that:

1. $U \vdash A \rightarrow C$
2. $U \vdash A \rightarrow (C \rightarrow B)$

Once again, this suggests to me that our hypothesis is *actually* of the form:

> For a proof length of size $n$, $\forall U, \forall A, \forall B \ \ \ \ $ If $U, A \vdash B$, then $U \vdash A \rightarrow B$

In this case, we are using concepts from a higher order logic system to facilitate the acquisition of a result in a lower order logic system (which seems a little fishy to me).

Am I misunderstanding something here?

Cheers~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For quantifiers, see [Universal generalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_generalization):

> (aka: Universal Introduction) is a valid inference rule. It states that if $\vdash P(x)$ has been derived, then $\vdash \forall x\,P(x)$ can be derived.

It amounts to the formal counterpart of the intuitive inference: "what holds for any, holds for all".

Thus, regarding the title question:

> What is the difference between proving something for an arbitrary object and proving something using a universal quantifier?

the answer is: we prove that the "universal generalization" of a property holds proving it for something arbitrary.

The *Deduction Theorem* is a meta-theorem, i.e. a result about the proof system. Thus, it is a "piece" of standard mathematics and not an expression of the formal system.

As often in modern mathematics, it uses a jargon that is a mixture of natural language ("if..., then...") and symbols ($\vdash$).

As often in mathematics, universal quantifier are implicit.

The theorem holds, for every set of formulas $\Sigma$ and every pair of formulas: $\varphi, \psi$ of the language.

Thus, regarding again the title question, we may say that:

> there is no difference between asserting something for an arbitrary object and asserting it using a universal quantifier.

Comment: Great response! For clarification, then, does the universal generalization fall underneath the category of “axiom”? I just want to make sure that it is not the consequence of some sentential order proof (i.e. i want to know that I don’t need the deduction theorem of sentential logic in order to ‘derive’ the universal generalization). I see that it’s referred to as a “rule” so I assume that it’s basically an axiom.

Comment: @S.Cramer - it depends... In most proof system (e.g. [Natural Deduction](https://iep.utm.edu/nat-ded/#H7)) it is an inference rule. In some it is derivable from axioms  in the form of a meta-theorem.

Comment: Just as a final inquiry...I’m sure there are whole posts dedicated to “metatheorems” but in the context of your post, can I view metatheorems as the following: “We create tools that allow us to examine the very tools we create” ...The metatheorem is the consequence of that examination. Is that the right idea? (So, in this post, predicate logic concepts allowed us to analyze sentential logic)

Comment: @S.Cramer - not exactly. It is only a convention: often we call a formula of e.g. prop logic that is derivable in the proof system (from axioms and rules, like e.g. $p \lor \lnot p$) a theorem (of propositional logic). A mathematical result "about" the proof system, like e.g. the Deduction Th and the Completeness Th are called meta-theorems, because they are not formula of the calculus but mathematical results expressing properties of the calculus.